# NgFor Counter or Sequence number Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-template

I would like to add a sequence of numbers for each loop in the ngFor

```
<template ngFor let-book [ngForOf]="books" let-i="index">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="isAuthor{{i}}">
</template>
```

If you see in "isAuthor" I would like to add a single number for each item inside of the ngFor

Any help with this?

thanks guys

Comment: I think you do not have to interpolate the ```{{i}}```. Could you try isAuthor(i) and see what happens ? Also, you cannot use the more "readable syntax" like ```<a *ngFor="let book of books; let i = index" (click)="isAuthor(i)"/>```

Comment: Thanks @DenkoMancheski, I've tried to add `{{i}}` or `(i)` or `[i]`. And I got the error that can't be assigned to a variable. It seems that angular doesn't like to use local variables as index, first, last inside another parameters.

Comment: That `class="javascript:void(0)"` doesn't do anything. You probably meant `onclick="javascript:void(0)"`. I guess `(click)="..."` won't work then anymore. Besides that What @DenkoMancheski suggested just works. There has to be some other problem in your code.

Comment: What is a "single number"? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? There is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What I am expecting is to assign a number for every for, I mean: First for i = 1, second i = 2, third, i = 3, etc. What I am trying to do it is assign this local variable `i` to an attribute like `isAuthor`. In this case, the first time will be isAuthor1, second isAuthor2, etc.

Comment: Where do you want to assign the number to? Is `isAuthor` a method in your component?